# Symfony2 Jquery Datatables Ajax Authentication failure after session expires

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables in a Symfony project. Below is my code to handle exception when session for the user expires and user tries to request data that loads in Jquery Datatable.

```
class AjaxAuthenticationListener
{
    /**
     * Handles security related exceptions.
     *
     * @param GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event An GetResponseForExceptionEvent instance
     */
    public function onCoreException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException || $exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                $event->setResponse(new Response('', 403));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my js file

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR) {
        if (403 === jqXHR.status) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
```

This works perfect except the fact that when "403 response" is returned as a response to Datatables, it gives an alert.

```
DataTables warning: table id=jq-datatables - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

When I click on this alert, page reloads. But is there a way that I should get this error silently in console and page still reloads?

I've already used this piece of code

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
```

But It stops the page from reloading. I do not want it that way.

Please help!